# Model attribute printing properly in view, but saved in the database as "nil" EDITED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I'm trying to write an app that calculates sick/vacation days and how much an employee has available in either category. Here's my trouble:

In my view, the *duration* equation works and shows the right numbers, but I've put the math in the view, which I know is bad. But when I try to use the *duration* equation in my employee class (so I can move the math out of the view) it doesn't work, and I think that it's because *duration* is saving as 'nil' for some reason. I don't know why it's doing that, as everything else has been saving in the database with whatever information I input into the form.

Maybe it's because *duration* isn't inputted manually in the form, but rather reacts to the date-range?

Here's where I want to call *duration* in the employee model to get the math out of the view:

```
  def remaining_vacation_days
    vacation_days - @furlough.duration if @furlough.description == "Vacation"
  end

  def remaining_sick_days
     sick_days - @furlough.duration if @furlough.description == "Sick" 
  end
```

Here's the model where duration is defined:

```
class Furlough < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :duration # and other stuff
  belongs_to :employee
  validates_presence_of :duration # and other stuff

  def duration
    only_weekdays(date_from..date_to) - psb_holidays
  end

  def only_weekdays(range)
    range.select { |d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size    
  end

  def psb_holidays
    Holidays.between(date_from, date_to, :us, :observed).size
  end

end
```

What's tripping me out is that in the console this is what I see:

```
1.9.3-p0 :008 > ryan = Furlough.find(18)
  Furlough Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "furloughs".* FROM "furloughs" WHERE "furloughs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 18]]
 => #<Furlough id: 18, duration: nil, date_from: "2013-12-20", note: "Christmas vacation!", created_at: "2013-05-08 14:33:03", updated_at: "2013-05-08 14:34:07", employee_id: 16, description: "Vacation", date_to: "2013-12-29">
```

See, it's nil, but then I get this:

```
1.9.3-p0 :009 > ryan.duration
 => 5
```

I'm at a loss.

Comment: If `duration` isn't saved from the form (e.g. using `update_attributes` or `new(params[:furlough]` etc.) it won't magically persist using a calculated value--you must calculate it yourself before saving it to the DB, one way would be to use callbacks.

Comment: do you have a duration function and a duration value in the db? as dave said you would need to use callback to set the duration,

Comment: Hmmm,  I've never heard of callbacks before. I'll research and study and come back after trying it out. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to use instance of the class, not the class itself, thats why you are getting all those errors.

```
def sick_days_used
   Furlough.duration if Furlough.description == "Sick"
end
```

should be :

```
def sick_days_used
   @furlough.duration if @furlough.description == "Sick"
end
```

or

```
def sick_days_used
   self.duration if self.description == "Sick"
end
```

if your are defining it in model

Comment: I tried your first option, and now I'm getting back "undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass", instead of "undefined method `description' for #<Class:0x007fa97613bee8>". What's the next question I should be asking/searching?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are attributes of a Furlough instance, not the Furlough class itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the methods as class methods then you need to add 'self' to the method definition:

```
def self.duration
  ...
end
```

Then you can call Furlough.duration.

The other way around (def duration) you are defining an instance method, which can only be called on an instance (an specifiic Furlogh instance).